# Is there a Slim iTunes 10 standalone installer?

Tags: itunes

I'm looking around for a standalone installer for iTunes 10 (whatever the latest version is).  I basically JUST want to install iTunes purely for the iTunes Store support so I can buy some music from there.

I know there's a slim iTunes install floating around for iTunes 9 - would I still be able to use iTunes 9 to access the store?

If not, anyone know of a slim standalone installer for the latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself. But [Ajua Online](http://www.ajuaonline.com/custom-installers/itunes/) offers a custom iTunes 10.6.3.25 (latest as of 2012-08-16) installer with the following modifications.

- Removed Bonjour service. If you share your iTunes library over a network, you wil need it. Just extract the Bonjour MSI file from the original iTunes installer (use either the 32-bit or 64-bit version) using 7-Zip or WinRAR and run it.
- Removed Apple Software Update. It won’t be scheduled to run periodically to check for updated versions of iTunes, Safari or QuickTime.
- Removed iTunes Helper. This is a process that loads at startup to supposedly help iTunes startup speed by pre-loading some data. This is not needed at all.
- It won’t associate itself with all the supported file formats. You can change that in its settings page if you want it to be your default player.
- It is installed for all users, unlike the original installer which install for the current user only.